# Python - Script to end scheduled task and event viewer tasks

Tags: python, scripting, taskscheduler, event-viewer

I have been searching for a while for the solution to end a scheduled task using python 3.

I have successfully managed to end a scheduled task BUT I have to end an 'Event Viewer Task'.

Im using the current code to end a scheduled task;

```
def endScheduledTasks():
    os.system('schtasks /end /tn testSync')
```

I assumed to end an event viewer task I would need to enter the following;

```
def endEventTasks():
    os.system('eventviewertask /end /tn Replication')
```

Any input on this would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your command

```
os.system('schtasks /end /tn testSync')
```

testSync is what?
if this is the name of process so you are get mistake.
look:

```
/TN  taskname    Specifies the path\name of the task to terminate.
```

try use "path_to_task\and_name_of_task"
for example:

```
schtasks /end /tn "\Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTask"
```

for see path_to_task and name_of_task:

```
schtasks
```

Comment: testSync is a scheduled task.

Comment: so use schtasks /end /tn "\Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTask" where \Microsoft\XblGameSave\XblGameSaveTask is full path and name task. without him i get error

Comment: Thank you for your help. The command I used was: os.system('schtasks /end /tn "\Event Viewer Tasks\TestTask"')

Comment: my congratulations to you

Comment: I have upvoted you but this is my first post. It does not appear public until 15 rep.